# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Silverlight' or one of its dependencies

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, version

I am a newbee to Silverlight and I am on it as I have inherited a sharepoint site that "used to" use Silverlight 2. I say "Used to" because the object tag in live .aspx pages says PARAM NAME="minRuntimeVersion" VALUE="2.0.31005.0". For some reason the development environment now produces param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40818.0" so I think the development environment has moved on to the next version. Now my problem is that I am not able to deploy any new build of the .xap files to the production environment even if I change the whole silverlight object in the UI. Any help would be much appreciated.

BTW, I get the following erro:
An error occurred during the processing of . Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Silverlight' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I can confirm the production environment has been updated with the newer version of Silverlight

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly ‘System.Web.Silverlight’ ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501348/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-silverlight)

Answer (score 1):

System.Web.Silverlight for v2.0 is under

%programfiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v2.0\Libraries\Server\

but this assembly has been **removed from the Silverlight SDK for Silverlight 3**, you should use object tag instead, see [this](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=153377) for more detail and also see [How to: Add Silverlight to a Web Page by Using HTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189089(VS.95).aspx)